# why is pushing my second nested array to localStorage breaking the JSON?

Tags: javascript, arrays

The first click gives me good data in `localStorage`, but adding another array breaks the JSON and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. Apologies for being a bit verbose, but wanted to recreate what's in the codebase as close as possible.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dpw645cy/7/)

```
<div class="wrap"></div>

<script>
var count = 4;
var target = document.querySelector('.wrap');

for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
        checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
        checkbox.id = 'id' + [i];
        checkbox.value = 'checkbox' + [i];
        checkbox.onclick = doClick;
        target.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', checkbox);


  var label = document.createElement('label');
      label.htmlFor = 'id' + [i];
      label.appendChild(document.createTextNode('compare ' + [i]));
      target.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', label);

  var data = [{
    title: 'title' + [i],
    handle: 'handle' + [i],
    specs: {
      a: '1',
      b: '2',
      c: '3'
    }
  }]

  console.log(data);

  function doClick() {
    arr.push(data);
    addToLocalStorageArray('arr', JSON.stringify(arr)); 
  }
}

var arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('arr') || '[]');

var addToLocalStorageArray = function (name, value) {

  // Get the existing data
  var existing = localStorage.getItem(name);

  // If no existing data, create an array
  // Otherwise, convert the localStorage string to an array
  existing = existing ? existing.split(',') : [];

  // Add new data to localStorage Array
  existing.push(value);

  // Save back to localStorage
  localStorage.setItem(name, existing.toString());

}

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `JSON.parse` to get the existing item and `JSON.stringify` to set it:

```
existing = existing ? JSON.parse(existing) : [];

localStorage.setItem(name, JSON.stringify(existing));
```

don't try to write your own json parsers / string methods.

Answer (score 0):

When converting the array to a string always use JSON.stringify() and when converting it back to an array use JSON.parse().
I hope it helps.